# Ionic 2: View does not update based on model change

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a very simple page with a couple of controls.

My issue is that the page does not pickup changes to the model when the icon in upper right corner is clicked. This toggles the showFilterPane variable, which again should show or hide a div based on *ngIf="showFilterPane".

I have another page just like this one working, and I can not figure out why this isn't.

Any tips?

(I've tried using the ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); which works, but then the rangeslider will not work. The draggable point doesn't update, or does not move to where you tap.)

The page:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>MY AO</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button (click)="toggleFilterPane()" icon-only>
        <ion-icon name="options"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      <div *ngIf="isSearching" class="spinner-container">
        <ion-spinner></ion-spinner>
      </div>
      <!-- put content here -->

    </div>

    <div class="right" *ngIf="showFilterPane">
      <ion-list inset>
        <ion-list-header>BANA</ion-list-header>        
        <ion-item>
          <ion-select multiple="true" [(ngModel)]="woTrackFilter">
            <ion-option>1</ion-option>
            <ion-option>2</ion-option>
            <ion-option>3</ion-option>
            <ion-option>4</ion-option>
            <ion-option>5</ion-option>
          </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
      <ion-list inset>
        <ion-list-header>TEKNIKSLAG</ion-list-header>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-select multiple="true" [(ngModel)]="woDisciplineFilter">
            <ion-option>Signal</ion-option>
            <ion-option>Bana</ion-option>
            <ion-option>EL</ion-option>
            <ion-option>Tele</ion-option>
          </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>    
      <ion-list inset>
        <ion-list-header>DAGAR</ion-list-header>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-range min="10" max="80" step="4" [(ngModel)]="woDaysFilter">
            <ion-label range-left>10</ion-label>
            <ion-label range-right>80</ion-label>>
          </ion-range>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
      <button ion-button (click)="doSearch()">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

The component:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { WorkOrderDashboardPage } from "../work-order-dashboard/work-order-dashboard";
@Component({
  selector: 'page-work-order-list',
  templateUrl: 'work-order-list.html'
})
export class WorkOrderListPage {
  private isSearching: boolean = false;
  private showFilterPane: boolean=false;
  private woTrackFilter: string[];
  private woDisciplineFilter: string[];
  private woDaysFilter: number;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    // Initialize storage providers here

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad WorkOrderListPage');
  }

  toggleFilterPane(): void {
    this.showFilterPane = !this.showFilterPane;
  }

  viewWorkOrder(event, workOrder): void {
    this.navCtrl.push(WorkOrderDashboardPage, { workOrder: workOrder });
  }

  doSearch(): void {
    console.log(this.woTrackFilter);
    console.log(this.woDisciplineFilter);
    console.log(this.woDaysFilter);
  }
}
```

**UPDATE: Found workaround**
I tried creating a separate app, where the exact same code is working. That lead me to think something wasn't right on the LoginPage, the page that called setRoot() to the above page.

The login code looked like this:

```
WLAuthorizationManager.login("UserLogin", data).then(() => {
  // Success
  console.log("Logged in");
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(WorkOrderListPage);    
},
(err) => {
  // failed
  console.error(err);
  this.showError("Username or password is incorrect");
})
```

I then figured it might be some Zone issue, and wrapped the setRoot call in zone.run() like this:

```
  WLAuthorizationManager.login("UserLogin", data).then(() => {
  // Success
  console.log("Logged in");
  this.zone.run(() => 
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(WorkOrderListPage)
  );    
},
(err) => {
  // failed
  console.error(err);
  this.showError("Username or password is incorrect");
})
```

After that the view started to respond as expected. I feel this is a bit of a hack. Can someone shed some light as to what is happening here?

Comment: I don't see **showFilterPane** defined anywhere in your code. Am I missing something or what? You are accessing it but it seems to be never declared (neither public/private nor protected)

Comment: I seem to have removed some code that wasn't commented before I posted. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are basically using ngZone to make sure Angular knows you changed things so it will reload that part of the DOM to reflect the changes. I don't feel like it's a hack, because you are just making sure that it works as intended.

Angular 2 has some optimization features that help make your app run smoother and one of those is avoiding DOM updates whenever and wherever possible. By using zones (or ngZones) you are basically telling Angular "pay attention to this part, it changes and I need that change to be reflected in the DOM".

I've run into that sort of problem before myself and using zones is usually your best bet. Got into situations where a part of the interface would be stuck unless you touched a button or somesuch.

Another workaround (at least for range sliders) is using the AppllicationRef tick() method, which forces a DOM update. More info about it [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ApplicationRef-class.html).